# Gluing for derived category of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a scheme and assume $X=U \cup V$ for two affine schemes $U_0$ and $U_1$. If $\mathcal F'$ and $\mathcal F''$ are some (coherent) sheaves on $U$ and $V$ respectively such that $\mathcal F'|_{U\cap V}\cong \mathcal F''|_{U\cap V}$, then we should be able to glue them and get a global sheaf $\mathcal F$ so that $\mathcal F|_U\cong \mathcal F'$ and $\mathcal F|_V\cong \mathcal F''$.

In analogy, let's assume $\mathcal F'$ and $\mathcal F''$ are elements in the derived categories $D(U)$ and $D(V)$ on $U$ and $V$ respectively, so that the restrictions $\mathcal F'|_U$ is *quasi-isomorphic* to $\mathcal F''|_V$. Then, can we still glue them to get a global thing in $D(X)$?

Comment: In general, gluing in derived categories is famously not nice--you need higher homotopical info to get existence and uniqueness of gluing in the appropriate sense. However, for just 2 open subsets you can get away with defining the gluing to be the triangulated analog of the usual kernel diagram that you use to glue ordinary sheaves.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Thank you. Could you be more precise about higher homotopical information? or any reference?

Comment: This expository article seems to have a lot of of info/references in it https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13373-018-0119-z#Sec1

Comment: See also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6170.pdf section 4.