# Sheaf of chain complexs glued by chain homotopy equivalences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, soft-question, kt.k-theory-and-homology, locally-ringed-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a locally ringed space with an open covering $\mathscr U$. Suppose:

- For any $U\in\mathscr U$, we have a chain complex $(C_U, d_U)$ such that $C_U$ is an $\mathcal O_X(U)$-module.
- For any $U,V\in \mathscr U$, we have a chain homotopy equivalence $f_{UV}: C_U|_{U\cap V} \to C_V|_{U\cap V}$
- For any $U,V,W\in \mathscr U$, we have that $f_{VW}\circ f_{UV}$ is chain homotopic to $f_{UW}$.

If I was not mistaken, we can take the homologies and glue them: the homologies $H_*(C_U,d_U)$ for $U\in\mathscr U$ form a $\mathcal O_X$-module on $X$.

However, taking the homologies at the start might lose some information. I was wondering if we can reverse the order. Namely, can we somehow 'glue' $(C_U,d_U)$ in the chain level first and take the homology later? Hopefully this was something well-known.

Comment: This sounds related to the idea of gluing objects of derived categories of sheaves. See some references in comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/340116/30186). In particular it seems that in order to perform gluing we need some "higher homotopical info" - we need not only that $f_{VW}\circ f_{UV}$ and $f_{UW}$ are chain homotopic, but rather we need a data of such a homotopy which satisfy even higher "coherence" properties.

Comment: Is your covering closed under intersections?

Comment: @JohannesHahn Yes, it should be.

Answer (score 2):

One way of packing the necessary data is the data of *twisting cochain* of
Toledo and Tong, see  [Duality and Intersection Theory in Complex Manifolds. I.](https://eudml.org/doc/182776).

What do they do: If you have an actual sheaf $\mathcal F$, you can reconstruct
it from restrictions $\mathcal F \vert_{U}$ and isomorphisms
$f_{UV}$ by taking the Čech resolution $C(\mathcal F, \mathscr U)$ (built out of sheaves like $i_{U*}\mathcal F\vert_U$;
see, for example, [the stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02FU))
and then taking its zeroth cohomology, or just leaving it be if you're only interested in the sheaf up to a quasiisomorphism.

Note that for building this Čech resolution one doesn't need the sheaf $\mathcal F$ itself, just restrictions and glueing functions are enough.
The cocycle condition $f_{UW} = f_{UV}f_{VW}$ is needed to ensure that
the Čech differential will square to zero. So the cocycle condition is kind of Maurer-Cartan equation for an appropriately defined dg-algebra
$C(\mathcal{End}(\mathcal F), \mathscr U)$.

A twisting cochain is a Maurer-Cartan element in an appropriately defined
dg-algebra $C(\mathcal{End}(\mathcal C^*), \mathscr U)$. This element
allows one to construct a Čech complex, which will be the totalization of
your $C^*_U$'s.

I don't know of a reference for *exactly* this fact, and I haven't checked
it thoroughly. From the looks of it, one wants the cover to be locally finite, and one does not necessarily want complexes to be bounded. There is
a lot of literature about the twisting cochains: see, for example, [this paper on homotopy limits of dg-categories](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eblockj/papers/HHA-2017-0019-0002-a017.pdf) by Block, Holstein and Wei, as well as other papers of each of these authors.